# Using the paypal adaptive payments api how can I set the payment type to PERSONAL?

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using the Adaptive Payments API and my payments are going through as a SERVICE payment - I can tell this by looking at the PaymentDetails after the payment has been completed. I want my payments to go through as Personal Payments so need to know how to be able to set the paymentType when using the PAY api.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

In the Adaptive Payments Pay API call - set the paymentType as PERSONAL. API ref here: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APPayAPI

Comment: if using adaptive payment ,can it be made for automatic fund transfer?